# Javascript that changes HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make javascript to when you enter variables to add code to html..? I don't know English too good, so..I'm going to draw it!
Also, I don't want it to change everything, but I want it just to add that
info to the list..I have premade HTML page with linked CSS.
If you have any questions, please ask me, just help me.. :(

I know HTML and CSS, java..Not even a little bit.. :/

[image]

If you are here reading this, THANK YOU! <3

Comment: Of Course you can, but instead of showing us a drawing - Add your code and what you've tried so far

Comment: yes, you can use javascript to modify the contents of a page. that's how pretty much every modern website does things these days.

Comment: What you've achieved so far?

Comment: I have this: HTML: http://pastebin.com/adbckBDt  CSS: http://pastebin.com/hwBCatig

Comment: If you are trying to display info1,info2,info3 , use ul http://codepen.io/pen/
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: I am trying to display thing that is written in java, as shown on pictures.

Comment: So you meant to say that if you are adding any object in list which is there in javascript the same object should be reflected in html page. i.e. all the previous objects plus the new one just got added? is it your question?

Comment: Exactly! Am..My English is not best, so i didn't knew how to say it..

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: HTML: pastebin.com/adbckBDt CSS: pastebin.com/hwBCatig

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help:

HTML:

```
<table class="table"><tr id="update-table"></tr></table>

<script>

(function(){

    var updater = (function(){

        function updater( options ){
            this.table = options.table;
            this.cells = this.table.querySelectorAll('.cell');
            this.num_cells = this.cells ? this.cells.length : 0;
        }

        updater.prototype.update_element = function( index, value ){

            this.cells[index].innerHTML = value;

        };

        updater.prototype.add_element = function(){
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.setAttribute('class','cell');
            this.table.appendChild(td);
            this.cells.push(td);
            this.num_cells++;
        };

        return updater;


    })();

    window.updater = updater;

})();


var table, a, count = 0;
table = document.getElementById('update-table');
a = new updater({table:table});

for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    a.add_element();
    a.update_element(i,'info'+i);
}

</script>
```

Comment: When i put that in my html, i get everything same, but i get "value::4
value::5
value::6
value::7" showed too... :/

Comment: Do you want to dynamically add new elements to the list and update them? I edited the code. If you remove the setTimeout() the elements keep the values you set as first. I thought you want to live update them within your script to keep track of whatever.

Comment: How did you mean that?

Comment: Do you just want to set the html of the given 4/5 list entries. Or do you need to update the text inside the list elements? If you only want to set the text for those elements remove the setTimeout(function(){....},1500) part from the script.

Comment: updated the script. It should do what is displayed on your image.

Comment: But it doesnt put form in what i can write and it doesnt put it in table

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to add html to your page through JavaScript.

1) Simply create a div with an id

```
<div id="enterTextHere"></div>
```

2) Inside of your custom.js file or inside of `<script></script>`, you can use many different methods

Method 1 : Using innerHTML

```
var desiredElement = document.getElementById("enterTextHere");
desiredElement.innerHTML = "<p>I added text!</p>";
```

Method 2 : Using JQuery.append

```
$("#enterTextHere").append("I added text!");
```

I'm sure there are many more but without your specific code to reference this is the best I can do. Please use this link for your reference. It also has a lot of good information for the rest of your HTML journey. Enjoy! [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

Comment: I want script to change content, but when i refresh page i want that content to save and that script is empty so i can add evan more content without replacing old one.

Comment: What you can do is utilize document.cookie. This will allow you to store all the list items in cookies. That way, you can write some Javascript code to read in the existing cookie and make the list that way.

Comment: Well, thats easy to tell, but im pretty new to programing in HTML and css.. :/

Comment: Cookies are limited and shouldn't be used to store arbitary data. HTML5 localStorage would be a good way for modern browsers or a caching engine that caches the lists and delivers them really fast.

Comment: Thank you user2429266. I didn't think about that. I used cookies before to do a breadcrumb list where it would store the user's previous urls and it worked fine. Cookies are easy to learn for a new beginner.